# How to make .htaccess rewrite rule for request filename work with directories with index files?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is the .htaccess I am using.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
 RewriteRule (.*)$ https://sub.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When a specific file path like path1/path2/index.html is requested, it works fine and and does't rewrite. But if a path like path1/path2/ is requested, it redirect even if there is a DirectoryIndex file like index.html in that directory. What is an easy way to fix this?

Comment: `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` should be `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1` or just `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}`

Comment: The way your rule is written (incorrectly, as stated by anubhava above) it is very unlikely to ever "redirect" (not "rewrite"). I'd wager you are probably seeing a cached redirect (301s are cached persistently by the browser). This really has nothing to do with DirectoryIndex documents. However, what are you actually trying to achieve? It looks like you are trying to do the exact opposite of what you were asking in [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73782373/is-there-a-way-to-only-execute-htaccess-code-if-the-file-isnt-found) (since deleted)?

Comment: @MrWhite What exactly I am trying to achieve is if the file on the first domain is there, nothing happens. But if the file isn't there I want the the .htaccess to redirect/rewrite (if that's possible) to the second domain but preserve the query string and url. I haven't found anything really useful on it and since I have only just started learning how to use .htaccess I haven't managed it.

Comment: Is it only when actual "files" don't exist (if so, what type of files) or directories as well (as your code perhaps suggests)? If it's only "files" then the rule could be made more efficient by removing the filesystem check for directories _and_ making the regex more restrictive (so that it only matches what could potentially be a file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suggested in comment above, something like this should work:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . https://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: From comments, it would seem the OP wants to do the opposite... "if the file on the first domain is there, nothing happens. But if the file isn't there I want the .htaccess to redirect".

Comment: Yes you are right @MrWhite I copy/pasted code from OP in rush. Thanks!!